# Filtering time series conditional on list of dates by week number (R)

Tags: r, time-series, subset, trading

I have a data frame containing a time sequence sampled every 30 minutes (for 2016). I need to make a subset containing every Wednesday 10:30:00 if the week contains no holiday falling on Sunday to Wedneday, and every Thursday 11:00:00 if the week contains a holiday falling on Sunday to Wedneday. This would create a schedule of EIA petroleum weekly report releases. I do not want to use xts.

I know how to subset by day of week and time of day. But I do not know how to subset conditional on the week containing a date present in a list of dates. How could I do that?

The code below creates a subset by day of week and time of day without filtering by holidays. It also includes the list of holiday dates to use as filter.

```
#Make time sequence every 30mins with Time & DayWk columns 
Calendar30mn <- as.data.frame(seq(as.POSIXlt("2016/1/1 00:00:00"), as.POSIXlt("2016/12/31 23:59:59"), by="30 mins"))
colnames(Calendar30mn) <- "DateTime"
Calendar30mn$Time <- strftime(Calendar30mn$DateTime, format="%H:%M:%S")
Calendar30mn$DayWk <- weekdays(Calendar30mn$DateTime)

#List of US Federal holidays falling on Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/Wedneday 
FedHolidaysSuntoWed <- structure(c(16818, 16846, 16951, 16986, 17049, 17161, 17084), class = "Date")  

-----

#Subset for Wednesday 10:30:00
EIAOildates1 <- subset (Calendar30mn, Time == "10:30:00" & DayWk == "Wednesday")

#Subset for Thursday 11:00:00
EIAOildates2 <- subset (Calendar30mn, Time == "11:00:00" & DayWk == "Thursday")

#Bind subsets and set reverse order (most recent at the top)
EIAOildates <- rbind(EIAOildates1, EIAOildates2)
```

The above code generates `EIAOildates1` containing a subset for Wednesday 10:30:00. I would like that subset to only contain Wednesday 10:30:00 if any day of that week is not present in `FedHolidaysSuntoWed`. And viceversa for `EIAOildates2`.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand your question, but I was wondering if you could use the `lubridate` package, more specifically, use the `week` function to generate the week number (e.g. 1 to 52/53). Given both the day of week and the week number, you could group the data.  I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Will look into it! BTW sorry to hear the question is not clear. Don't think can make any clearer, but I'll try.

Comment: `lubridate` has some nice functions to check if a date falls within a given interval. Check its vignette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
library(lubridate)

#Make time sequence every 30mins with Time & DayWk & WkNumber columns 
Calendar30mn <- as.data.frame(seq(as.POSIXlt("2016/1/1 00:00:00"), as.POSIXlt("2016/12/31 23:59:59"), by="30 mins"))
colnames(Calendar30mn) <- "DateTime"
Calendar30mn$Time <- strftime(Calendar30mn$DateTime, format="%H:%M:%S")
Calendar30mn$DayWk <- weekdays(Calendar30mn$DateTime)
Calendar30mn$WkNumber <- week(Calendar30mn$DateTime)

#List of US Federal holidays falling on Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/Wedneday & Corresponding WkNumber
FedHolidaysSuntoWed <- structure(c(16818, 16846, 16951, 16986, 17049, 17161, 17084), class = "Date")  
FedHolidaysSuntoWedWkNumber <- week(FedHolidaysSuntoWed)

#Subset for Wednesday 10:30:00
EIAOildates1 <- subset (Calendar30mn, Time == "10:30:00" & DayWk == "Wednesday"
                        & !(Calendar30mn$WkNumber %in% FedHolidaysSuntoWedWkNumber))

#Subset for Thursday 11:00:00
EIAOildates2 <- subset (Calendar30mn, Time == "11:00:00" & DayWk == "Thursday"
                        & (Calendar30mn$WkNumber %in% FedHolidaysSuntoWedWkNumber))

#Bind and sort subsets  
EIAOildates <- rbind(EIAOildates1, EIAOildates2)
EIAOildates <- EIAOildates[(order(as.Date(EIAOildates$DateTime))),]
```

This is a sample of the output of EIAOildates:

```
                 DateTime     Time     DayWk WkNumber
262   2016-01-06 10:30:00 10:30:00 Wednesday        1
598   2016-01-13 10:30:00 10:30:00 Wednesday        2
983   2016-01-21 11:00:00 11:00:00  Thursday        3
1270  2016-01-27 10:30:00 10:30:00 Wednesday        4
1606  2016-02-03 10:30:00 10:30:00 Wednesday        5
1942  2016-02-10 10:30:00 10:30:00 Wednesday        6
2327  2016-02-18 11:00:00 11:00:00  Thursday        7
16726 2016-12-14 10:30:00 10:30:00 Wednesday       50
17062 2016-12-21 10:30:00 10:30:00 Wednesday       51
17447 2016-12-29 11:00:00 11:00:00  Thursday       52
```